# in microservice not able to run client with spring framework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

0

i am using jdk 1.8 only and the problem is not during server run. It is during a client run and for normal client works fine. Problem starts when whole of spring framework(includes security, audit, data jpa and JWT).

For me also works with client with only one main string class, but starts when whole of spring framework application.

All examples on net are found only with one class.

what do i do for this???

Comment: can you share log/exception message?

Comment: For me also works with client with only one main spring* class, but starts when whole of spring framework application.

Comment: please help me...

Comment: if you can share pom.xml and error message, that would be helpful.